# zeros of Riemann zeta function.

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is, is $z = 0$ is zero of Riemann zeta function? 
   by putting z $= 0$ in Riemann functional equation 
$$\zeta(z) = [2(2\pi)^{z-1}]\times\zeta(1-z)\times\Gamma(1-z)\times\sin(\frac{\pi z}{2})$$ one can see that sin terms get $0$ and hence R.H.S. becomes zero. so is zeta function has zero at $z = 0$ ?

Comment: $\zeta(0)=-1/2$

Comment: yes i had read book in which ζ(0) = -1/2 is given but there they had omitted a proof. 
i am confusing about how sin term get cancel? and further Γ function has a pole at 0, -1, -2,... not at +1

Comment: The problem that I see is $\zeta(1-z)$ has a pole at $z=0$, so this product does not make sense at $z=0$.

Comment: please see this short proof. which shows ζ(z) = 0 when z = 0.
 ζ(z)/ Γ(1-z) = [2(2π)^z-1]• ζ(1-z) • sin(πz/2)
 from this we can see that L.H.S. is zero when Γ(1-z) is infinity and we know 
   Γz = infinity if z = 0,-1,-2,...  this imply
 Γ(1-z) = infinity if z = 1,2,3,....
 hence L.H.S = 0 When z = 1,2,3,...
and hence R.H.S = 0 When z = 1,2,3....
hence ζ(1-z) • sin(πz/2) = 0 when z = 1,2,3...
but we know that sin(πz/2) = 0 when z = 2, 4,6,..
this imply 
 ζ(1-z) = 0 when z = 1,3, 5,...
this imply ζ(z) = 0 when z = 0, -2,-4, -6...

Comment: $\zeta(0)=\pi^{-1} \lim_{x \to 0} {\zeta(1-z) \sin(\pi z/2)}=-1/2$ (since $\lim_{x \to 0} {\sin(x)/x}=1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \zeta(x) x=1$)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** From the formula obtained for even numbers:

\begin{equation}
\zeta(2k)= \frac{(2\pi)^{2k}(-1)^{k+1}B_{2k}}{2(2k)!}
\end{equation}
If we take $k=0$, we get:
\begin{equation}
\zeta(0)= \frac{-B_{0}}{2(0)!}=-\frac{B_0}{2}
\end{equation}
Finally as $B_0=1$
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}

**Method 2:** Also, from the formula obtained for negative numbers:

\begin{equation}
\zeta(-k)=(-1)^k\frac{B_{k+1}}{k+1}
\end{equation}
If we take $k=0$, we get:
\begin{equation}
\zeta(0)= B_{1}
\end{equation}
Since $B_{1}=-\frac{1}{2}$, we also obtain:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}

**Method 3:** Also if we take the limit in zero of the functional relation:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta(0)&=&\lim_{s\to 0} \pi^{s-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\zeta(1-s)\\
&=&\lim_{s\to 0} \pi^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\zeta(1-s)\\
&=&\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\zeta(1-s)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

But $\zeta(s)\approx \frac{1}{s-1}$ lorsque $s\to 1$ (voir \ref{eq_zeta1}) and $\Gamma(s)\approx \frac{1}{s}$ lorsque $s\to 0$ (voir \ref{eq_gamma_zero}). Donc

\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta(0)&=& \lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{(1-s)-1}}{\frac{2}{s}}\\
&=& -\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

We still get:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}